# Redux and localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and haven't found any concrete examples that help in explanation of localStorage and Redux.

I am currently working on a mini application, where I am fetching data from an endpoint and rendering on the page. In addition, I have an option to pin the posts which will show in a "Pinned" section.

I want to save all the pinned posts into localStorage. When the page refreshes, I want to show all the pinned posts even if the post is no longer returned from the endpoint.

In my current implementation, I can fetch data and allow the user to toggle between pinning and unpinning the post. The user can the see post in "Pinned" section and "Posts" section accordingly.

**My Post Component**

```
class Post extends Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }

    pinPost(id, val){
        this.props.pinPost(id, val)
    }

    render(){
        let pinedPosts = [];
        let postItems = [];

        this.props.posts.forEach(post =>{
            if(post.data.pinned){
                pinedPosts.push(
                    <div key={post.data.id} className="listBox">
                        <div className="listContent">
                            <i className='fa fa-thumb-tack pin' style={{color:"green"}} onClick={this.pinPost.bind(this, post.data.id, false)}></i>
                            <a href={'https://someapi' + post.data.permalink} target="_blank">{post.data.title}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }else{
                postItems.push(
                    <div key={post.data.id} className="listBox">
                        <div className="listContent">
                            <i className="fa fa-thumb-tack pin" onClick={this.pinPost.bind(this, post.data.id, true)}></i>
                            <a href={'https://somepai' + post.data.permalink} target="_blank">{post.data.title}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Pinned</h1>
                {pinedPosts}
                <hr/>
                <h1>Posts</h1>
                {postItems}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**My Actions**

```
import {FETCH_POST, PIN_POST} from './types';

export function fetchPost() {
    console.log('fetch..');
    return function (dispatch) {
        fetch('https://someapi/....')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(posts =>
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_POST,
                    payload: posts.data.children
                })
            )
        ;
    }
}

export function pinPost(id, val) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: PIN_POST,
            id,
            val
        });
    }
}
```

**My Reducer**

```
import {FETCH_POST, PIN_POST} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: action.payload});
        case PIN_POST:
            const item = state.items.map(value => value.data.id === action.id ?
                {data: Object.assign({}, value.data, {pinned: action.val})} : value
            );
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: item });
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**My Main Store**

```
import { createStore,  applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

//... Do i handle the localStorage implementation here?

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

export default store;
```

I am not sure how to incorporate hydrating the redux store with any previously saved state from local storage when the page refreshes.

Comment: you should take a look at https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist its a middleware which helps to persist redux store.

Comment: Interesting, do you know if I can persist/whitelist based on an action. I have only one reducer that handles fetching posts and pinning the posts.

Comment: I think you should create two reducer one for your posts which are fetched from server and one for the pinned posts and you should persist the pinned post reducer state.

Comment: But this would mean I have to share the state between reducers.

Comment: if you dont like that then take a look at https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter this allows you to persist only a sub property of a reducer.

Comment: If you really want "Pinning" as a feature of your mini application it probably needs to be persisted somewhere on a server. Local Storage will pin for a little while, but if a computer or laptop restarts poof its gone. If its just for a demo and you want to stick purely to a client app using redux, localStorage is still independent, so you can write to local storage from a single action like ```localStorage.setItem(pin: result);```